# How many number of cyclic subgroup of order $12$ of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z×\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z×\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z ×\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

How many number of cyclic subgroup of order $12$ of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z×\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z×\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z ×\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ ?

I think first try is to count the number of element of order $12$, and that is $2\times 3\times 3\times 2=36$ (element of order of $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ need to be 4).

The number of element of order $12$ and the number of subgroup of order $36$ may be related, I think I need to divide $36$ by some number .

Is my attempt right? And how can I correctly deal with it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing that's clearly relevant is that two elements of order 12 that are powers of one another generate the same cyclic subgroup. Just think about the dumb case where the group is just $\mathbb{Z}/12$ itself. There's only one group, but there's $\varphi(12)$ elements of order $12$, where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler totient.

Comment: Thank you ! Then, the number of subgroup is 36÷φ(12)＝36÷4＝9 ？

Comment: The component in Z/3Z x Z/3Z can't be zero,

Comment: The number of elements of order $12$ is $32$, not $36$.

Comment: How did you gained $32$ ? Can it be gained by direct calculation?

Comment: In your calculation, you need to replace the $3 \times 3$ by $3 \times 3 - 1 = 8$, as explained in the comment by Anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G=C_2\times C_3\times C_3\times C_4$ (here, $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.) By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the cyclic subgroups $A\subseteq G$ of order $12$ correspond to pairs $(B,C)$ of a cyclic subgroup $B\subseteq G$ of order $3$ and a cyclic subgroup $C\subseteq G$ of order $4$. (given by $A\mapsto (3A,4A)$ and $(B,C)\mapsto B\times C$, the inner direct product).

Now, the order $3$ cyclic subgroups $B\subseteq G$ are just order $3$ subgroups of $C_3\times C_3$, which is simple to count. Similarly, the order $4$  cyclic subgroups $B\subseteq G$ are just order $4$ subgroups of $C_2\times C_4$.